# Focus not returning to CView after dismissing Message box

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog, focus, messagebox

Within a derived CView class' method, I am calling the CWnd's MessageBox method.  This is a docked view, not an MDI child.  Upon return from MessageBox, focus goes to the Active MDI child, not back to the docked view.

Thinking this was an MFC behavior "anomaly", I tried changing the code to use the Win32 ::MessageBox and pass in the view's GetSafeHwnd() for the parent HWND paraneter, and the view STILL doesn't get focus upon dismissal of the MessageBox, but the Active MDI child gets focus, just like the MFC call.

Also, I see similar behavior with CDialog-based windows from the view, not just MessageBox's.

I did a work-around by calling SetFocus() AFTER returning from MessageBox, and that works.  However, **I don't want to have to programatically ALWAYS set focus back to me** (there's some situations where the view or one of its children do NOT have focus BEFORE the dialog/message box, so I actually need to test for that BEFORE the dialog/message box, then restore focus only if I HAD focus, AFTER the call to DoModal/MessageBox).

Is this an MDI Windows behavior bug?  Is this not a bug but a "desired feature" of MDI apps?  Am I doing something wrong?  Anybody have any ideas or comments?